# Removing all stopwords defined in a file from a text in another file (Python)

Tags: python, file, stop-words

I have two text files:

1. Stopwords.txt --> contains stop words one per line
2. text.txt --> big document file

I'm trying to remove all occurences of stopwords (any word in the stopwords.txt file) from the text.txt file **without using NLTK** (school assignment).

How would I go about doing this? This is my code so far.

```
import re

with open('text.txt', 'r') as f, open('stopwords.txt','r') as st:
    f_content = f.read()
    #splitting text.txt by non alphanumeric characters
    processed = re.split('[^a-zA-Z]', f_content)

    st_content = st.read()
    #splitting stopwords.txt by new line
    st_list = re.split('\n', st_content)
    #print(st_list) to check it was working

    #what I'm trying to do is: traverse through the text. If stopword appears, 
    #remove it. otherwise keep it. 
    for word in st_list:
        f_content = f_content.replace(word, "")
        print(f_content)
```

but when I run the code, it first takes forever to output something and when it does it just outputs the entire text file. (I'm new to python so let me know if I'm doing something fundamentally wrong!)

Comment: You seem to be calling `st.read()` outside of your with block, meaning st will be closed. Also, what is the problem with this code so far?

Comment: hey @JammyDodger thanks for the reply! I've updated my original question ^ with the problem. If you could help that would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use when I need to remove English stop words. I usually also use the corpus from nltk instead of my own file for stop words.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
ps = PorterStemmer()

## Remove stop words
stops = set(stopwords.words("english"))
text = [ps.stem(w) for w in text if not w in stops and len(w) >= 3]
text = list(set(text)) #remove duplicates
text = " ".join(text)
```

For your special case I would do something like:

```
stops = list_of_words_from_file
```

Let me know if I answered your question, I am not sure if the problem is the read from file or the stemming.

Edit: 
To remove all stopwords defined in a file from a text in another file, we can use str.replace()

```
for word in st_list:
    f_content=f_content.replace(word)
```

Comment: thats the strategy I wanted to go for but we're not allowed to use NLTK... we've been given a text file with a bunch on stopwords they want us to remove from the document file...any suggestions?!? thanks!!!

Comment: So you only need to delete certain words from a text? No stemming involved?

Comment: yes, so for example stopwords.txt is [a, the, it, from] and the text.txt is [Hello I am from the UK] should become [Hello I am UK]. I also need to stem but thats the next step! i've managed to get the stem working but i need to remove the stop words first.

Comment: Check the snippet I added in the edit. Didn't get to test it, but should work.

Comment: hey! i think the snippet has the right thought in mind but the replace method didn't work because it was expecting two arguements (I updated that in my code above) but im still having problems :(

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact you are facing performance issues. I would suggest using the `subprocess` library ([for Python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), or [for Python3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html)) to call the `sed` linux command.

I know Python is really good for this kind of thing (and many others), but if you have a really big text.txt. I would try the old, ugly, and powerful command-line 'sed'.

Try something like:

sed -f stopwords.sed text.txt > output_file.txt

For the stopwords.sed file, each stopword must be in a different line and using the format below:

```
s|\<xxxxx\>||g
```

Where 'xxxxx' would be the stopword itself.

```
s|\<the\>||g
```

The line above would remove all occurrences of 'the' (without single quotes)

Worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think this kind of worked... but it's incredibly slow so if anyone has any suggestions on how to make this more efficient I'd really appreciate it!

```
import re
from stemming.porter2 import stem as PT


with open('text.txt', 'r') as f, open('stopwords.txt','r') as st:

    f_content = f.read()
    processed = re.split('[^a-zA-Z]', f_content)
    processed = [x.lower() for x in processed]
    processed = [PT(x) for x in processed]
    #print(processed)

    st_content = st.read()
    st_list = set(st_content.split())

    clean_text = [x for x in processed if x not in st_list]
    print clean_text
```